# WEBRTC - Webcamera Source and View

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webrtc

i am new to WEBRTC. i have two html pages that supposed to capture and show webcamera respectively. my expectation is that "webcamerasrc.html" page should capture webcamera and through "WEBCAMERAVew.html" page, one can view the camera. the first page is capturing the video but the second page is not showing it. i think webrtc handshake is not getting completed . any suggestion regarding making things work or understand webrtc handshake or sdp exchange between two diffrent pages would be appreciated .

Here are the snippets.

webcamerasrc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>WEB CAMERA SOURCE</title>

    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src="https://webrtcexperiment-webrtc.netdna-ssl.com/RTCPeerConnection-v1.5.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>WEB CAMERA SOURCE</h1>


<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="localVideo">

    </video>
    <video autoplay="true" id="rVideo">

    </video>
</div>

     <script>


     var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/IntegrateIntoWebTest/websocket');





        var mediaConstraints = {
            optional: [],
            mandatory: {
                OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
                OfferToReceiveVideo: true
            }
        };


        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
        window.RTCPeerConnection = window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        window.RTCSessionDescription = window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.RTCSessionDescription;
        window.RTCIceCandidate = window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate;

        var isChrome = !!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
        var STUN = {url: isChrome ? 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' : 'stun:23.21.150.121' };
        var TURN = {url: 'turn:homeo@turn.bistri.com:80', credential: 'homeo'};
        var iceServers = {iceServers: [STUN, TURN] };
        var DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement = {DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true};
        var optional = {optional: [DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement]};
        var video = document.getElementById('localVideo');
        var offerer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);

        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, VideoSuccess, VideoError);
        }



        function VideoSuccess(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            offerer.addStream(stream);



             offerer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
                   if (!event || !event.candidate) return;
                   var o_icecandidate = event.candidate;
                   socket.send(JSON.stringify({o_icecandidate}));

                   socket.onmessage = function(event) {

                     var iceData = JSON.parse(event.data);

                      console.log(iceData);

                    offerer.addIceCandidate(iceData);

                    };


               };

            offerer.onaddstream = function (stream) {
                //alert(stream.stream);
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream.stream);
           };


        }

            offerer.createOffer(function (offerSdp) {

                offerer.setLocalDescription(offerSdp);
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({offerSdp}));

        }, function(e) {console.log(e);}, mediaConstraints);


         socket.onmessage = function(event)
             {

                   //alert(JSON.parse(event.data.answerSdp));
                  // alert(answerSdp);
                   //if(answerSdp='answer'){var remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(answerSdp);offerer.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);}
                    var  actualData = JSON.parse(event.data);

                    console.log(actualData);
              if(actualData.answerSdp.type='answer')
              { 
                  console.log(event.data);
                    var sd = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    console.log(sd.answerSdp);
                    var sd1 = new RTCSessionDescription(sd.answerSdp);
                    console.log(sd1);
                    offerer.setRemoteDescription(sd1);
              }



             }




        function VideoError(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }




    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

WEBCAMERAVew.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>REMOTE WEB CAMERA VIEW</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>REMOTE WEB CAMERA VIEW</h1>

<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
<script src="//cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCPeerConnection-v1.5.js"> </script>

<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="localVideo">

    </video>
    <video autoplay="true" id="rVideo">

    </video>
</div>

     <script>
          var myDataRef = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/wsTest/websocket');

          myDataRef.onmessage = function(event) {

             var  actualData = JSON.parse(event.data);

              if(actualData.offerSdp.type='offer')
              { answererPeer(event);}

            };





    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [],
        mandatory: {
            OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
            OfferToReceiveVideo: true
        }
    };



    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    window.RTCSessionDescription = window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.RTCSessionDescription;
    window.RTCIceCandidate = window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

    var isChrome = !!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    var STUN = {url: isChrome ? 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' : 'stun:23.21.150.121' };
    var TURN = {url: 'turn:homeo@turn.bistri.com:80', credential: 'homeo'};
    var iceServers = {iceServers: [STUN, TURN] };
    var DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement = {DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true};
    var optional = {optional: [DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement]};

    var answerer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
    var video = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('rVideo');





                function answererPeer(event) {
                    //window.alert(offer.sdp);
                    //window.alert(video_stream);


                     var sd = JSON.parse(event.data);
                     var rd = new RTCSessionDescription(sd.offerSdp);


                    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
                        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, VideoSuccess, VideoError);
                    }


                    function VideoSuccess(mediaStream)
                     {
                         //answerer.addIceCandidate(icecandicate.candidate);


                         answerer.addStream(mediaStream);


                            answerer.setRemoteDescription(rd);



                            answerer.createAnswer(function (answerSdp) {

                                 answerer.setLocalDescription(answerSdp);
                                 myDataRef.send(JSON.stringify({answerSdp}));

                             }, function() {}, mediaConstraints);



                         answerer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
                             if (!event || !event.candidate) return;

                                var a_icecandidate = event.candidate;

                             myDataRef.send(JSON.stringify({a_icecandidate}));

                             myDataRef.onmessage = function(event) {

                                 var  iceData = JSON.parse(event.data);

                                console.log('over here : '+iceData);


                                };





                         };

                         answerer.onaddstream = function (mediaStream) {
                            alert(mediaStream);
                             remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
                             remoteVideo.play();
                         };



                    }

                    function VideoError(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }


                }
            </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "but nothing is working". What have you tried? What were the results? What were your expectations? We can't just read your entire code and fix your problems. [See this page to learn how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for asking a senseless question. I should have never done that. my expectation is that "webcamerasrc.html" page should capture webcamera and through "WEBCAMERAVew.html"  page one can view the camera. the  first page is capturing the video but the second page is not showing it. i think webrtc handshake is not getting completed . any idea why ?????